# How to measure performance differences of query in oracle

Tags: sql, performance

I am running a simple select query on oracle server A And on Oracle server B

How can measure query performance differences between the two servers?
I need to get simple data like execution time,latency  etc

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you run [tkprof](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=tkprof%20) before? or used [autotrace](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=autotrace%20oracle)? If you are trying to measure things from the command line, say SQLPlus, then tkprof may be the way to go but you can also use autotrace. From inside SQL Developer, then autotrace is easier I think. Look up those terms on Stack Overflow and you'll probably find that the question has been asked a few times before.